# Handling JSON Array from Android in Rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json

I am trying to post a JSON Array to a rails web service. Everything works fine with JSON Object. But with JSON Array I am getting a null result.

Here is my code:

**1. Creating JSON Array**

```
JSONArray tickerArray = new JSONArray();

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    JSONObject jsonObjForArray = new JSONObject();

    jsonObjForArray.put("activity_id", "10100");
    jsonObjForArray.put("player_id", i);
    jsonObjForArray.put("time", i * 100 + i * 5);
    jsonObjForArray.put("game_id", game_id);

    tickerArray.put(jsonObjForArray);

}

Log.i(TAG, tickerArray.toString(2));
```

With following result:

```
[
   {
     "activity_id": "10100",
     "player_id": 0,
     "time": 0,
     "game_id": "6",
   },
   {
     "activity_id": "10100",
     "player_id": 1,
     "time": 105,
     "game_id": "6",
   },
   {
     "activity_id": "10100",
     "player_id": 2,
     "time": 210,
     "game_id": "6",
   }
]
```

**2. Send the HttpPostRequest**

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(tickerArray.toString());

// Set HTTP parameters
httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
    if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
         instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
    }

    String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
    instream.close();
    Log.i("resultString", resultString);
    ...
```

My resultString:

```
 {"activity_id":null,"created_at":"2016-01-29T09:55:49Z","game_id":null,"id":450,"player_id":null,"time":null,"updated_at":"2016-01-29T09:55:49Z"}
```

Everything is null except "id", "created_at", "updated_at". On my web service I got **one** (instead of **three**) new but empty entry.

What went wrong? Thank you for help.

**Edit I - My rails controller**

```
  # POST /ticker_activities
  # POST /ticker_activities.json
  def create
    puts params
    @ticker_activity = TickerActivity.new(params[:ticker_activity])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticker_activity.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ticker_activity, notice: 'Ticker was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @ticker_activity, status: :created, location: @ticker_activity }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @ticker_activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Edit II - Passed JSON Array and handling**

After placing `puts params` in my create method this is the result in my logs:

```
{"_json"=>[{"activity_id"=>"10100", "player_id"=>0, "time"=>0, "game_id"=>"6"}, {"activity_id"=>"10100", "player_id"=>1, "time"=>105, "game_id"=>"6"}, {"activity_id"=>"10100", "player_id"=>2, "time"=>210, "game_id"=>"6"}], "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"ticker_activities", "format"=>"json", "ticker_activity"=>{}}
```

So passing from android to rails seems to be ok. Question is how to handle this in rails?! I found a solution for importing CSV files:

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

        ticker_hash = row.to_hash 
        TickerActivity.create!(ticker_hash)

    end
end
```

Is there anything similar for JSON arrays?

Comment: maybe something on the rails side? post some server side code..

Comment: I added the controller in rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Rails controller expects params to be a hash like this:

```
{
  ticker_activity: {
    activity_id: "10100",
    player_id: 0,
    time: 0,
    game_id: "6",
  }
}
```

Check that it is by placing `puts params` on the first line of the `create` action in the controller. If it isn't you'll probably have to change either your client side to send appropriate json that your server expects or your server side to handle arrays.

**Re Edit II:**

To convert the params you're getting from the POST from android, you could do something like the following:

```
params["_json"].each do |params_hash|
  ticker = TickerActivity.create!(params_hash)
end
```

However, you should be careful here; just passing all params without whitelisting them leaves you open to a mass assignment attack. Rails recommends using strong parameters to avoid this (read more here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), so I'd recommend doing something like this instead.

```
params["_json"].each do |params_hash|
  whitelisted_params = params_hash.permit(:activity_id, :player_id, :time, :game_id)
  ticker = TickerActivity.create!(whitelisted_params)      
end
```

The convention in Rails is to follow restful routing and the convention for the create action is to save only a single resource (i.e. only a single ticker_activity). Therefore I'd suggest you create an entirely new controller action in your Rails controller to handle the creation of **multiple** ticker activities.

1. Add the following line to your Rails app's routes.rb file:

   ```
   post '/multiple_ticker_activities', to: 'ticker_activities#create', as: :multiple_ticker_locations
   ```
2. Then change your android app to post its json data to `/multiple_ticker_activities.json`.
3. And then add the following new controller action.

   ```
   # POST /multiple_ticker_activities
   # POST /multiple_ticker_activities.json
   def create_multiple
     puts params

     @ticker_activities = params["_json"].map do |params_hash|
       whitelisted_params = params_hash.permit(:activity_id, :player_id, :time, :game_id)
       TickerActivity.new(whitelisted_params)      
     end

     respond_to do |format|
       # Check that all the ticker_activities are valid and can be saved
       if @ticker_activities.all? { |ticker_activity| ticker_activity.valid? }
         # Now we know they are valid, we save each ticker_activity
         @ticker_activities.each do |ticker_activity|
           ticker_activity.save
         end

         # and then respond with the json versions of the saved ticker_activites
         format.json { render json: @ticker_activities, status: :created, location: multiple_ticker_locations_url }
       else
         # Since at least some of the ticker_activities are invalid,
         # we can't save *all* the ticker_activities, so we
         # respond with the validation errors instead
         @errors = @ticker_activities.map { |ticker_activity|
           ticker_activity.errors
         }
         format.json { render json: @errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end
   ```

(Note: This controller action only handles json formatted requests. It doesn't handle html formatted requests. You won't need it to handle html requests if **only** your android app is using this action. However, if that's not the case and you do want it to handle html as well then you'll first need to decide where to redirect to following a successful save. Because I don't know how your app is structured, and you probably don't need to handle html anyway, I left out html support).

This should fix your problem (unless I've made any typos).

Comment: I will check this but I think I have to change my server side to handle arrays.

Comment: Yep. That's what it seems to me.

Comment: I edited my question. May question now is how to handle json array in rails.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it is still not working. First I guess it should be |params_hash| with s. Now I am getting an error: (undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass). With "@ticker_activity = TickerActivity.new(params_hash)" instead of "ticker = TickerActivity.create!(params_hash)". That works but it only saves the last hash. Probably I have to call another method from android than create, do the loop in that method and call create from that method. But how?

Comment: Ah, you're right I had a typo in the first example. I've corrected. In relation to the error you're getting, since you're now creating multiple ticker activities you're going to get an error if you keep the rest of the code the same. I've edited my answer to show a possible amendment.

Comment: Yeah. That's it. You have to delete one curly bracket after "# Respond with the json versions of the saved ticker_activites". Now it works. Thank you!

Comment: ... and: You are right. I just want to handle json formatted requests. No html.

Comment: Glad I could help. (Oops you're right. I've removed that extra curly bracket)